# How can I get the length of an arbitrary data frame when piped in using Tidyr?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have code like this:

```r
bulk <- read_csv("data/food_bulk_raw.csv") %>% 
  mutate(Treatment = "bulk", Individual = seq_len(Timestamp))
```

`seq_len()` is creating a list of `1:length(Timestamp)`. It works because 'Timestamp' is a column of the data-frame. But let's say I didn't know anything about my data-frame: Perhaps I am creating a function. How could I indicate the length of the data-frame without first saving it as an object like I have below?

```r
data002 <- read_csv("data/data002.csv")

data002 <- mutate(data002, New_Column = 1:nrow(data002))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use any of the following

```
library(tidyverse)
#Option 1
read_csv("data/food_bulk_raw.csv") %>% 
  mutate(Treatment = "bulk", Individual = seq_len(nrow(.)))

#Option 2
read_csv("data/food_bulk_raw.csv") %>% 
     mutate(Treatment = "bulk", Individual = seq(nrow(.)))

#Option 3
read_csv("data/food_bulk_raw.csv") %>% 
      mutate(Treatment = "bulk", Individual = sequence(nrow(.)))
```

All of these do not depend on any column but uses `nrow` to create sequence.

Also as @Marius commented, you could also use `n()` which returns number of rows instead of `nrow`. So in all of the above options `nrow(.)` can be replaced with `n()`.

Apart from that we can also use `row_number`

```
read_csv("data/food_bulk_raw.csv") %>% 
       mutate(Treatment = "bulk", Individual = row_number())
```

To demonstrate, making a function

```
df_sequence_func <- function(df) {
  df %>% mutate(Individual = seq_len(nrow(.)))
}

df_sequence_func(mtcars)

#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb Individual
#1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4          1
#2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4          2
#3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1          3
#4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1          4
#....

df_sequence_func(cars)

#   speed dist Individual
#1      4    2          1
#2      4   10          2
#3      7    4          3
#4      7   22          4
#5      8   16          5
#6      9   10          6
#....
```

It returns a sequential row number irrespective of the columns or rows in the dataframe.

Comment: You can also use `dplyr::n()` instead of `nrow(.)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, seq_len(.N)]
```

and it can be read with `fread`

```
fread("data/food_bulk_raw.csv")[, 
     c("Treatment", "Individual")  := .("bulk", seq_len(.N))][]
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(data002, 'rn')
```

Or using

```
data002 %>%
      mutate(New_Column = seq_len(n()))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df$newcolumn <- seq(nrow(df))
```